# Clone working for an element but not for entire div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Explanation: I am trying to clone elements / div. I am trying to achieve it by right clicking on them opening up a context menu and clicking on "clone" option.

I have a very simple code, let me show you -

```js
(function ($, window) {

    $.fn.contextMenu = function (settings) {

        return this.each(function () {

            // Open context menu
            $(this).on("contextmenu", function (e) {
                // return native menu if pressing control
                if (e.ctrlKey) return;
                
                //open menu
                var $menu = $(settings.menuSelector)
                    .data("invokedOn", $(e.target))
                    .show()
                    .css({
                        position: "absolute",
                        left: getMenuPosition(e.clientX, 'width', 'scrollLeft'),
                        top: getMenuPosition(e.clientY, 'height', 'scrollTop')
                    })
                    .off('click')
                    .on('click', 'a', function (e) {
                        $menu.hide();
                
                        var $invokedOn = $menu.data("invokedOn");
                        var $selectedMenu = $(e.target);
                        
                        settings.menuSelected.call(this, $invokedOn, $selectedMenu);
                    });
                
                return false;
            });

            //make sure menu closes on any click
            $('body').click(function () {
                $(settings.menuSelector).hide();
            });
        });
        
        function getMenuPosition(mouse, direction, scrollDir) {
            var win = $(window)[direction](),
                scroll = $(window)[scrollDir](),
                menu = $(settings.menuSelector)[direction](),
                position = mouse + scroll;
                        
            // opening menu would pass the side of the page
            if (mouse + menu > win && menu < mouse) 
                position -= menu;
            
            return position;
        }    

    };
})(jQuery, window);




$("#container").contextMenu({
    menuSelector: "#contextMenu",
    menuSelected: function (invokedOn, selectedMenu) {
  
        var msg = "You selected the menu item '" + selectedMenu.text() +
            "' on the value '" + invokedOn.text() + "'";
   //var itsId = $(invokedOn).attr('id');
   var selectedText = $(invokedOn).get(0).outerHTML;
   var parentDiv = $(invokedOn).parent();
        alert(selectedText);
  if (selectedMenu.text() == "Clone"){
   //alert("inside");
   $(invokedOn).clone().insertAfter(invokedOn);
  }
    }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>


<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="content">content</div>

    <div id="content2">
 <p>This is p </p>
 <h3> This is h3 </h3>
 </div>  
    
</div>



<ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="display:none" >
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Clone</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
 
</ul>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="contextmenu.js"></script>



</body>
```

Run the code and Right click on "this is p" or "this is h3" and select clone, they will be cloned but i also want to clone entire div according to my selection. This requirement works for me on click but dont know how to do it by context menu, see this code here, the below code will work with left click, see this pic, i can clone entire div or single element depending on my area of click, same thing i want above with right click - https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqftyt96s75jc6b/Screenshot%202017-04-07%2013.38.30.png?dl=0

```js
$('*').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
 var thisDiv_name = $(this).attr('id');
 var thisDiv = $(this);
 var parentDiv = $(this).parent();
   // $(this).clone().appendTo(parentDiv); 
   $(this).attr('style','outline: #6c6b69 solid thin;');
$(this).clone().insertAfter(thisDiv);
//alert($(this).html());    
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">content</div>
    <div id="content2">
 <p>This is p </p>
 <h3> This is h3 </h3>
 </div>
    <button id="button">show it</button>
</div>



</body>







</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you could implement a new context menu item which clones the `parent()` element of one which triggered the event.

Also note that you can tidy up the logic by using a `data` attribute to specify the action to be performed instead of matching the text. Try this:

```js
!function(a,b){a.fn.contextMenu=function(c){function d(d,e,f){var g=a(b)[e](),h=a(b)[f](),i=a(c.menuSelector)[e](),j=d+h;return d+i>g&&i<d&&(j-=i),j}return this.each(function(){a(this).on("contextmenu",function(b){if(!b.ctrlKey){var e=a(c.menuSelector).data("invokedOn",a(b.target)).show().css({position:"absolute",left:d(b.clientX,"width","scrollLeft"),top:d(b.clientY,"height","scrollTop")}).off("click").on("click","a",function(b){e.hide();var d=e.data("invokedOn"),f=a(b.target);c.menuSelected.call(this,d,f)});return!1}}),a("body").click(function(){a(c.menuSelector).hide()})})}}(jQuery,window);

$("#container").contextMenu({
  menuSelector: "#contextMenu",
  menuSelected: function($invokedOn, $selectedMenu) {
    var action = $selectedMenu.data('action');
    switch (action) {
      case 'cloneEl':
        $invokedOn.clone().insertAfter($invokedOn);
        break;
      case 'cloneParent':
        var $parent = $invokedOn.parent();
        $parent.clone().insertAfter($parent);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/* CSS is only to make the output more obvious */
p { background-color: #CC0; }
h3 { background-color: #0CC; }
#container > div { 
  border: 1px solid #C00; 
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="content">content</div>
  <div id="content2">
    <p>This is p </p>
    <h3>This is h3</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="display:none">
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-action="cloneEl">Clone</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-action="cloneParent">Clone parent</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-action="another">Another action</a></li>
</ul>
```